# Using JS i need to create a Average variable

Tags: javascript

hi i need to create a Average variable that will average out my grades any help will be greatly appreciated i have the following.  but i cant figure out the average portion of it

my code works for the  inputs and gets the grades,  and i also have the html portion 
and i have an empty p tag for all of the inner html

```
function myFunction(){

let math = document.getElementById("math").value;
let science = document.getElementById("science").value;
let history = document.getElementById("history").value;
let english = document.getElementById("english").value;
let average = ( [ "math","science","history","english",  ] );



// this is match sec
if(math >= 90) {
    document.getElementById("mathG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is A"
}

else if (math >= 80 && math < 90) {
    document.getElementById("mathG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is B"
}

else if (math >= 70 && math < 80) {
    document.getElementById("mathG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is c"
}

else if (math >= 60 && math < 70) {
    document.getElementById("mathG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is d"

}

else  {
    document.getElementById("mathG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is F"

}

// Science section

if(science >= 90) {
    document.getElementById("scienceG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is A"
}

else if (science >= 80 && science < 90) {
    document.getElementById("scienceG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is B"
}

else if (science >= 70 && science < 80) {
    document.getElementById("scienceG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is c"
}

else if (science >= 60 && science < 70) {
    document.getElementById("scienceG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is d"

}

else  {
    document.getElementById("scienceG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is F"

}

// History

if(history >= 90) {
    document.getElementById("historyG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is A"
}

else if (history >= 80 && history < 90) {
    document.getElementById("historyG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is B"
}

else if (history >= 70 && history < 80) {
    document.getElementById("historyG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is c"
}

else if (history >= 60 && history < 70) {
    document.getElementById("historyG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is d"

}

else  {
    document.getElementById("historyG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is F"

}

//English
english

if(english >= 90) {
    document.getElementById("englishG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is A"
}

else if (english >= 80 && english < 90) {
    document.getElementById("englishG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is B"
}

else if (english >= 70 && english < 80) {
    document.getElementById("englishG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is c"
}

else if (english >= 60 && english < 70) {
    document.getElementById("englishG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is d"

}

else  {
    document.getElementById("englishG").innerHTML = "Your Grade is F"

}
```

Comment: There are several different ways of doing it, but the easiest one is quite straightforward. How would you compute that average manually?

Comment: It looks like you put a great effort into your code. I warmly suggest you to read about functions, as they'll save you a lot of time and allow you to get more A's!

Answer (score 0):

The code will be like this I guess :

```
let average  =  math + science + history + english / 4;
```

Here you will get the average and with the **if else** like you did for getting grades for each subject you can find the average grade as well.

```
if(average >= 90) {
  average  = "A";
}
```

Tip: You can use loop or map to reduce the line of code.

Comment: Calculating your average without parentheses results in a big mistake

Answer (score 0):

`history` is a global in browsers, so you can't use it as a variable name.
You should do something like:

```
let mathGrade = document.getElementById("math").value;
let scienceGrade = document.getElementById("science").value;
let historyGrade = document.getElementById("history").value;
let englishGrade = document.getElementById("english").value;

let average = (mathGrade + scienceGrade + historyGrade + englishGrade) / 4
```

Then, if you want the 'average' letter grade, you can do something similar to what you did for the other grades using the average:

```
if(average >= 90) {
    document.getElementById("averageG").innerHTML = "Your Average Grade is A"
}

else if (average >= 80 && average < 90) {
    document.getElementById("averageG").innerHTML = "Your Average Grade is B"
}

else if (average >= 70 && average < 80) {
    document.getElementById("averageG").innerHTML = "Your Average Grade is c"
}

else if (average >= 60 && average < 70) {
    document.getElementById("averageG").innerHTML = "Your Average Grade is d"

}

else  {
    document.getElementById("averageG").innerHTML = "Your Average Grade is F"

}
```

Comment: can you  share what  you mean by (Then, if you want the 'average' letter grade, you can do something similar to what you did for the other grades using the average. ???

Comment: You can reuse `history` if you want...just not if you also want to use it to refer to the global. (If you `let` it in a function, it will no longer be the global `history`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- First, make sure to cast your inputs to a number. It works with strings when doing a comparison with `>` or `<`, but if you try to add strings together with `+`, it will concatenate them rather then summing their numeric values.
- Second, you can shorten your code by putting the duplicated if/else chains into a function.

Anyway, an average is just a sum divided by the number of summed items, so:

```
let average = (math + science + history + english) / 4;
```

would work. Or you can use a `reduce` if you have them in an array. This might come in handy if you frequently add or remove subjects:

```
let scores = [math, science, history, english];
let average = scores.reduce((total, score) => total + score) / scores.length;
```

Anyway, here's a snippet that seems to be working how you want:

```js
function calculateAllGrades() {
  let math = Number(document.getElementById("math").value);
  let science = Number(document.getElementById("science").value);
  let history = Number(document.getElementById("history").value);
  let english = Number(document.getElementById("english").value);
  // let average = ( [ "math","science","history","english",  ] );
  
  // Hardcoded, okay if these are all subjects:
  let average = (math + science + history + english) / 4;
  
  // Or if they change, you can use an array, easier if they change or you add more:
  let scores = [math, science, history, english]
  average = scores.reduce((sum, score) => sum + score) / scores.length 

  function calculateGrade(score, elementID) {
      const element = document.getElementById(elementID);
      if (score >= 90) {
          element.innerHTML = "Your Grade is A";
      } else if (score >= 80) {
          element.innerHTML = "Your Grade is B";
      } else if (score >= 70) {
          element.innerHTML = "Your Grade is C";
      } else if (score >= 60) {
          element.innerHTML = "Your Grade is D";
      } else {
          element.innerHTML = "Your Grade is F";
      }
  }

  calculateGrade(math, "mathG")
  calculateGrade(science, "scienceG")
  calculateGrade(history, "historyG")
  calculateGrade(english, "englishG")
  calculateGrade(average, "averageG")
}

let button = document.getElementById("button")
button.addEventListener("click", calculateAllGrades)
```

```html
<div>MATH:<input type="text" id="math" /></div>
<div>SCIENCE:<input type="text" id="science" /></div>
<div>HISTORY:<input type="text" id="history" /></div>
<div>ENGLISH:<input type="text" id="english" /></div>
<br />
<div>MATH:<div id="mathG"></div></div><br/>
<div>SCIENCE:<div id="scienceG"></div></div><br/>
<div>HISTORY:<div id="historyG"></div></div><br/>
<div>ENGLISH:<div id="englishG"></div></div><br/>
<div>AVERAGE:<div id="averageG"></div></div><br/>

<button id="button">Calculate</button>
```